# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter can not parse "Etc/GMT" time zone

Tags: java, parsing, java-8, timezone

I am trying to use java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter to parse dates like "2017-04-03 19:16:19 Etc/GMT" and getting `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-04-03 19:16:19 Etc/GMT' could not be parsed at index 20`

Here is how my formatter is being initialized:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz");
```

At the same time, if date is as follows: "2017-04-03 19:16:19 Etc/**UTC**", everything works great.

I checked `java.time.ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` - String "Etc/GMT" is in the list (technically, in the Set).

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"`

Comment: That was quick! Thank you! Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Question is not useful for others. [Javadoc of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) already shows that `V` is the format letter for matching named time zones, not `z`. Just delete the question.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm the only one out there who can waste a couple of hours on stuff like that...

Comment: @Andreas - That's worth putting in an answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"`:

```
V       time-zone ID                zone-id           America/Los_Angeles; Z; -08:30
z       time-zone name              zone-name         Pacific Standard Time; PST
```

As you can see, the `V` pattern will format/parse a Zone Id, like `America/Los_Angeles` and `Etc/GMT`, while the `z` pattern only formats/parses the Zone Name.

The `V` pattern must be at least 2 long, i.e. `VV`.